# Asp.Net Api Redirect Request to Different Endpoint

Tags: asp.net-core

I would like to redirect requesets internally from one controller to another but am not sure how to do this. Ideally, I would like to specify the name of the controller where the request should be redirected to and optionally the name of the action (not always needed for standard get requests). I know that there is a `Redirect(...)` method, however, it only takes a url as a parameter. I would like to avoid using an url because server address may change depending on location.

**Test1 Contoller**

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/test1")]
public class Test1Controller : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("users")]
    public IActionResult GetUsers()
    {
        // redirect to users controller
        // return Redirect(...); ??
    }
    
    [HttpGet("companies")]
    public IActionResult GetCompanies()
    {
        // redirect to companies controller
        // return Redirect(...); ??
    }
}
```

**User Contoller**

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/user")]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetUsers()
    {
        // List of users are returned here
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Company Contoller**

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/company")]
public class CompanyController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetCompanies()
    {
        // List of companies are returned here
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Either tag a question with "asp.net" = framework (old) or "asp.net core" not both, as they are quite different

Comment: You can use relative path in `Redirect(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`RedirectToAction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.redirecttoaction). E.g.

```cs
[HttpGet("users")]
public IActionResult GetUsers()
{
    return RedirectToAction("GetUsers","User");
}
```